# Need help getting a try and catch to work

Tags: java, crash, try-catch, user-input

In the first try and catch it works exactly how I need it to however in the other two they don't and I am not sure why.

First One: It asks for a difficulty 1 - 3 if it isn't 1,2, or 3 it loops till they enter 1,2 or 3 and if they put anything but an int it will say "Invalid Difficulty" and ask for them to input again.

Issue: None (that I know of)

```
try {
    System.out.println("What would you like the difficulty to be?");
    System.out.println("Easy = 1, Medium = 2, Hard = 3");
    difficulty = userInput.nextInt();

    while((difficulty < 1 || difficulty > 3)){
        System.out.println("Invalid Difficulty. \n");           
        difficulty = userInput.nextInt();
    }
} catch(InputMismatchException exception) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Difficulty.\n");
    difficulty = selctDifficulty();    
}
```

Second One: Should do the same as above just without the loop to male sure it falls between 2 numbers.

Issue: If they don't enter an int it says Invalid amount then crashes with

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

try {
    System.out.println("How many pitchers would you like to buy?");
    amountOfPitchers = userInput.nextInt();
} catch(InputMismatchException exception) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Amount.\n");
    amountOfPitchers = userInput.nextInt();
}
```

Third One: Should work exactly as the first.

Issue: If I enter a string it crashes with

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

try {
    System.out.println("How much do you want to charge per cup?");
    System.out.println("Between $0.05 and $2.00");
    pricePerCup = userInput.nextDouble();

    while((pricePerCup < 0.05 || pricePerCup > 2.00)){
        System.out.println("Invalid Amount. \n");           
        pricePerCup = userInput.nextDouble();
    }
} catch(InputMismatchException exception) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Amount.\n");
    pricePerCup = userInput.nextDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first appears to be recursive in the catch block, your third isn't...

```
System.out.println("Invalid Amount: " + userInput.next()); // <-- read the non-double.
// pricePerCup = userInput.nextDouble();
pricePerCup = selectPricePerCup();
```

Comment: So what I have to do is make a method and call the method in order for it to loop like it is in the first and not just ask for the input in the catch it self.

Comment: Or write an actual loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your error line tells you clearly what and where the error is:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Something in your catch clause for your second and third example is giving you error, but not the first one. Do you see why?

Upon simple inspection, for your second and third try and catch, after an exception has occured due to invalid input, your are still attempting to process input using userInput.nextInt() and userInput.nextDouble(). The exception this causes will not be caught and is therefore causing problems.

You need to do userInput.next() in your catch in order to move to the next input

Comment: Thanks that really helped me see what the error was saying.

Answer (score 0):

Cause you do `pricePerCup = userInput.nextDouble();` in catch?

If you catch it why you try to process input once again when it is not valid input?
Read about exceptions and what catch block really does.